# Child Expandable list not accept match_parent because of onMeasure()

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I am using expandable list for making 3 - level hierarchy, functionally its
working as needed but I am facing some GUI related issue thats its
wrap_content applied for custom child expandable list and my requirement is
to make it match_parent.

I have tried couple ways not able to figure out the solution for it, In one
trial I come to know that if I remove onMeasure() its appear as needed
(covering whole width of parent list) but its own child group is not
visible.

In order to make 3 level hierarchy I am referring below tutorial.

http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c991d70a-4570-4e4b-8378-2191a4247a84

Please advised/Approach for making child ExpandableList to cover whole